# Traduction « streaming »

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Je cherche à éviter le terme anglais « *streaming* » pour parler d'un service qui fonctionne en flux réseau plutôt que par téléchargement.

Or, je trouve, que « en flux » sonne très mal.

Comment: Google translate fait l'anglicisme http://translate.google.fr/#en|fr|streaming et traduit "streaming" par "en streaming"

Comment: Je connais à la fois des gens qui consomment des contenus en *streaming* et des gens qui travaillent sur les logiciels de diffusion et de réception, et je suis à peu près sûr que tous utilisent spontanément *streaming*, comprendraient *en flux*, et n'auraient aucune idée de ce que peuvent bien vouloir dire les autre propositions avancées dans les réponses. Donc si tu veux être compris, utilise *streaming* ou à la rigueur « en flux (*streaming*) ».

Comment: @Gilles c'était ma réponse au départ, mais la fibre lyrique… :p

Comment: À la place de _flux_, il existe aussi **flot** :-)

Comment: streaming, c'est de l'anglais intranscriptible, donc **non**, laissez le franglais à Google et aux Vichyssois intellectuels ; *flux* me semble parfait, donc *en flux* ?

Comment: La bonne nouvelle, c'est que la généralisation de la technique "streaming"  va rendre inutile le terme (vu que tout les vidéo ou presque seront du *streaming*), qui n'aura plus vraiment de traduction. De la même façon qu'"automobile" a quasi-disparu au profit de "voiture", ou bien que "smartphone" est remplacé par "téléphone" tout court.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comme d'habitude dans ce genre de cas *streaming* est sûrement la meilleure solution, puisque tous ceux que le *streaming* intéresse utilisent déjà ce terme et ne comprendront peut-être pas tout de suite un autre. Mais si tu tiens absolument à néologir tu peux essayer

- *vidéo en direct*
- *[lecture en transit](http://fr.bab.la/dictionnaire/francais-anglais/lecture-en-transit)*
- *diffusion liquide*
- *[diffusion en continu](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/live+streaming.html)*

Comment: +1 De bonnes propositions. Notamment, j'aime assez *diffusion en continu*. Avec la variante éventuelle *diffusion continue*

Comment: Sur la même ligne (haha), pourquoi pas *transmission continue*. *Diffusion* ne me semble pas être le bon mot.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, c'est juste, *transmission* est plus pertinent. A la limite, pour garder la racine de *flux*, pourquoi pas *transmission fluide* ?

Comment: +1 pour « néologir » :p J'aime beaucoup *diffusion en continu*, qui rejoint d'ailleurs une des recommendations de l'OQLF.

Comment: @Circeus Tu n'as encore rien vu on a plein d'idées avec Stéphane ;-p Encore mieux, je propose : *en fluxion* C'est le meilleur rapport sémantique/verbosité, et il est quasi-littéral...

Comment: @Dilbert: si tu veux du littéral et du court, *en ruisseau* c'est pas mal non plus. En tout cas moi ça me plaît :-p

Comment: *En continu* conviendrait bien, étant donné qu'un flux est un mouvement ininterrompu.

Comment: [_Diffusion en continu_](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8873293), OQLF 2015.

Comment: les propositions sont intéressantes (quoique vidéo soit inutilement restrictif puisqu'on peut écouter de la musique en flux !), en revanche le préambule qui justifie inconditionnellement le franglais est culturellement SUICIDAIRE, heureusement que ceux qui ont créé le vocabulaire informatique français par exemple n'avaient pas ces idées de démission ; laissons la reddition inconditionnelle aux nazis et continuons avec autant de courage que de culture et d'intelligence la francisation de la langue … aidés par les Canadiens francophones qui sont parfois brillants.

Answer (score 5):

Suite aux concertations habituelles du public (voir https://wikilf.culture.fr/), la traduction homologuée du substantif "streaming" est paru au Journal Officiel du 21 janvier 2015. Il s'agit de la locution "écoute ou diffusion en flux", ce qui semble simple et adéquat.

Définition : Se dit de la diffusion ou de la réception par l'internet de contenus audio et vidéo, selon un mode de transmission permettant une lecture en continu sans téléchargement.

Voir : http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=streaming&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search

N.B. : je ne peux qu'encourager les personnes soucieuses de disposer rapidement de vocables français pour le jargon technologique anglo-saxon à intervenir et faire des propositions sur le site https://wikilf.culture.fr/. C'est la meilleure manière de contribuer efficacement à une traduction rapide, adaptée et coordonnée. L'Académie et les dictionnaires ne font qu'entériner bien plus tard...

Comment: L'entrée de FranceTerme que vous proposez est _en flux_ tout court ; ça remplace l'entrée _diffusion en flux_ du 18 janvier 2005... _Diffusion en flux_ depuis 10 ans maintenant. Merci.

Comment: bravo. En flux est français, explicite, simple, pourquoi chercher midi à quatorze heures ?!

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait également* proposer **transmission fluide**, qui a le mérite de conserver la racine de *flux*.

** (pour faire suite aux commentaires de la réponse d'Evpok)*

---

*Edition suite à une remarque éclairée :*

Ou bien, pour éviter une confusion possible avec l'idée d'une transmission quelconque mais qu'on qualifierait de *régulière*, je propose **en fluxion**. Oui, le terme existe déjà, mais avec un sens trop différent pour qu'on puisse soupçonner une confusion. Ca sonne un peu étrange, mais c'est court et très littéral, je crois que je serais capable de m'y faire...

Comment: Je déconseille « transmission fluide », qui a déjà un sens différent. Une transmission fluide, c'est une transmission sans accroc, par exemple une vidéo que l'on voit en pleine résolution et en temps réel, par opposition à une vidéo qui aurait des à-coups. Une transmission en *streaming* peut donc ne pas être fluide, par exemple à cause d'un débit insuffisant du canal de transmission.

Comment: @Gilles *fluide* n'est pas synonyme de régulier. La circulation du sang dans les vaisseaux obéit à la mécanique des fluides, mais elle a pourtant un rythme par à-coups. Elle peut même s'interrompre... (ce qui a, convenons-en pour l'anecdote, plus de gravité qu'une vidéo youtube qui se fige ^^) Je t'accorde en revanche que quand on parle aujourd'hui de *transmission fluide*, on ne fait que qualifier *transmission* et *fluide* prend le sens de *régulière et/ou abondante*

Comment: Allez, c'est ma dernière offre : *en transfluxion*.

Comment: @RomainValeri – vu le préambule d'Evpok, je ne pensais pas que le sourire me reviendrait dans la suite de ma lecture de cette page …