# Verbe correspondant au mot « néologisme » : néologir ?

Tags: usage, verbes, néologismes

Dans la réponse de l'utilisateur @Evpok
à cette question [Traduction « streaming »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/traduction-streaming/2905#2905)
on lit :

> Comme d'habitude dans ce genre de cas streaming est sûrement la meilleure solution, puisque tous ceux que le streaming intéresse utilisent déjà ce terme et ne comprendront peut-être pas tout de suite un autre. Mais si tu tiens absolument **à néologir** tu peux essaye (...)

Le verbe **néologir** existe-t-il ? Je n'arrive à le trouver nulle part. Est-il un néologisme ? Comment serait sa conjugaison ?

Comment: d'habitude les verbes néologisants sont du premier groupe (en `-er`), mais là voir néologir un verbe du second groupe ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, bien sûr, ce verbe est un néologisme. C'est un mot nouveau construit par dérivation et il n'apparaît pas dans les dictionnaires. Il a le mérite d'être facilement compréhensible et de combler un manque.

Ce n'est pas sa première occurrence. On le trouve déjà employé [il y a plus de vingt ans](https://groups.google.com/g/fr.rec.jeux.jdr/c/0vF8gRnaVkI):

> Blop, l'adjectif existe mais j'avoue avoir néologi l'adverbe.
> (néologir : verbe du deuxième groupe, créer un néologisme.)
>
> Hypocoristiquement,
> Jym.

Il est en concurrence avec un ancien néologisme, *néologiser*, qui a plus de chance de subsister car appartenant au premier groupe de conjugaison. Les néologismes d'autres groupes sont rarissimes, le dernier connu étant *alunir*.

Answer (score 1):

Non, ce verbe n'est pas un néologisme ; c'est le résultat d'un besoin d'exprimer l'idée « introduire un néologisme/nouveau mot », de « créer un néologisme », ce que ce verbe devrait signifier si on l'adoptait ; il aurait normalement dû être placé entre guillemets.

- Mais si tu tiens absolument à « néologir » tu peux essaye (...)

Par contre, « néologiser » (créer un néologisme) n'est [pas du tout un néologisme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A9ologiser). On le trouve dans d'autres dictionnaires, comme le Wiktionnaire et le Larousse. Cela rend la perspective d'adopter « néologir » très peu probable.

Comment: Quelle est ta définition de néologisme ? Pourquoi *néologir* ne mériterait pas ce qualificatif ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il me semble qu'avant que l'on puisse parler de néologisme, il faut un certain nombre d'occurrences ; un hapax n'est pas caractérisé comme étant aussi un néologisme. Comme je n'ai trouvé aucun cas de « néologir », j'ai pensé que ça ne pouvait pas en être un.

Comment: Les mots ne naissent-ils pas libres et égaux ?

Comment: @jlliagre Un intéressant sujet de dissertation…